# Bind json data to datatable with empty Error array

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a json data that consist of a Error empty array. I am unable to bind the data On trying to bind the data using datatable code. Code works when I remove the 'DATA' and 'ERROR' from my json data.

I have tried the below code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#example').dataTable({
            "data" : user_data,
            "bDestroy" : true,
            "deferRender" : true,

            "columns" : [ {
                "data" : "ID"
            }, {
                "data" : "Code"
            }, {
                "data" : "PlaceID"
            }, {
                "data" : "FirstName"
            },

            ]
        });

    });
```

this is the json data:

```
 var user_data= {

  "DATA": [{
    "ID": "222",
    "Code": "1",
    "PlaceID": "26",
    "FirstName": "ABC "
}, {
    "ID": "235",
    "Code": "1",
    "PlaceID": "6",
    "FirstName": "ABC "
}, {
    "ID": "236",
    "Code": "1",
    "PlaceID": "68",
    "FirstName": "ABC "
}, {
    "ID": "237",
    "Code": "1",
    "PlaceID": "38",
    "FirstName": "ABC "
}, {
    "ID": "238",
    "Code": "1",
    "PlaceID": "18",
    "FirstName": "ABC "
}, {
    "ID": "239",
    "Code": "1",
    "PlaceID": "49",
    "FirstName": "ABC "
}],"ERROR": []
};
```

If data is present in the json it should bind in datatable if not, it will throw an error. through the empty error array.

Comment: You're missing a comma before `"ERROR"` in your JSON data file, and not all browser support dangling commas (so remove the comma after `"ERROR": [],` if you're not using something like Babel to transpile your code)

Comment: It was my mistake while adding the code here, sorry.